# Freezes on loading screen after boot

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I've installed Kali 2020.1 as a VM using VirtualBox and get stuck on the dragon loading screen after I boot up and after grub. See attached image. My current virtual machine settings are:

- Memory: 2048 MB
- CPUs: 2
- Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX, KVM Paravirtualization
- VRAM: 128 MB
- Graphics Controller: VMSVGA

I've also tried running the Virtualbox image supplied from Kali (from [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)). Either way, if I install it using the installer ISO or using the prepared Vbox file, I get the same error. It loads grub and when it comes to the dragon loading screen, it freezes when the blue glow get to about where it is in the attached image. I have tried messing with the settings to no avail, and I've also double checked that I have turned on Intel Virtualization Technology in the BIOS.

I also tried to install Ubuntu to see if that worked, but it also got stuck on the loading screen (the one with five dots and the Ubuntu logo). Installing Kali and Ubuntu on my laptop works, but not on my workstation (where the presented problem occurs). So it might be a problem with my computer, but I'm not sure what.

Please ask if there is any more information I should supply. Any help is appreciated!

[image: Stuck on Kali loading screen]

Comment: At Boot-Menu press [e] to edit boot options. Search the line with 'quiet splash' at the end and delete the two options. Then you can boot this entry with [Ctrl]-[x] or [F10] and see the boot output.

Comment: @hirnwunde Okay, I did, but I don't have the experience with kernels to understand what I'm looking at. It might not be of any worth, but I uploaded a screenshot of the point where it freezes: https://imgur.com/A9JkgoK   Is there anything that stands out that looks wrong?

Comment: I added the kernel log output (same Imgur link as above) from starting in single user mode and using the nomodeset option as well. It gets a kernel panic saying "not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler". What does this mean?

Comment: What version of VirtualBox you are using?

Comment: I've seen that Kali 2020 is using a relative new Kernel (5.4). Maybe you have to use the newest (or a recent) version of VirtualBox.
I"m using VMWare Workstation 15.5 on Manjaro with Linux 5.4.22 and Kali 2020 is running fine. Unfortunately I have no VirtualBox available

Comment: I'm using Virtualbox 6.1.6, the newest version, but it didn't have an effect. The VM still froze on the same point.

Comment: I downloaded the 32-bit version of Kali linux and it boots fine, so I'm guessing for some reason my system won't boot the 64-bit version. It weird, because it worked earlier, but suddenly stopped. Maybe a Windows update?

Comment: If the host is windows then i found out there are issues with Hyper-V and the newest Kali. Seems that if Hyper-V is enabled this is used for virtualization by default. Afaik only 32bit Kali runs on this. I tried to disable Hyper-V and my Kali 64bit 2020.4 started up nicely. hope this helps.